# HTML Formatting that just doesn't want to work

Tags: html, css

Simple html formatting that I just can't seem to gt right.

I have the following div:

```
<div class="fc-event-time" data-hasqtip="true" aria-describedby="qtip-6">
      2:54 - 6:54
    <i class="icos-refresh" style="float: right; margin-top: -17px; margin-right: 2px"></i>
    <i class="icos-acces-denied-sign" style="float: right; margin-top: -17px; margin-right: 2px"></i>
</div>
```

that according to firebug has the following css classes acting on it:

```
padding-left: 5px;
white-space: nowrap;
font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px !important;
padding: 0px 1px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
cursor: pointer;
direction: ltr;
text-align: left
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
line-height: 18px;
```

Now the above code is rendering like below:

[image]

if you can see, there are two icons on top of one another, `the <i></i> elements', my problem is that I would like to have it side by side. My first thought was to add`display:block;` but that doesn't work. how can I have them line up rather than superimposed?

**UPDATE:**

After taking out the `margin-top: -17px;` I get the following results, but I need them (the text and the icons) to be in the same row.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Finally Figured out the problem and fixed this issue, it turned out to be the `2:54 - 6:54` plain text that was not allowing the `<i>`s to get in the same line. all I did was modify the Full Calendar source to place the time inside a `<span>` and gave it a style attribute of `float: left' and its all lined up and working now. Thank you all for helping, if a better answer is submitted (one that I don't need to modify the javascript I will still award it as an answer since that would be a better method.

Comment: I really can't, the project is so complex and so many files in play. I'm sorry. This is a jquery fullcalendar plugin. and this is the header of an event. Besides the inline styles (above) the I did go through and list all the css attributes acting on the div and the elements though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `i` tags in that way?

Comment: Also: Try giving the div `overflow: auto`

Comment: @DA honestly, I purchased a theme and that's how they display icons :)

Comment: the 'i' tag is really odd one to use. Semantically, it means something rather specific in HTML5. Beyond that, though, it's an inline element, so I do think some of the advice to make the `i` either block or inline-block is a good place to start. It likely also needs defined dimensions.

Comment: @DA. so, I went a head and changed it to to `div`s and started taking out the styles one by one to see whose the culprit. It turns out that the problem lies with the `margin-top: -17px;` if I take it out I get the above (update) layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you don't have any widths applied to your `i` icons, plus the negative margin-tops could be playing havock with the floats. If you define actual widths for your `i` elements you shouldn't have a problem (at least based on what I can see).

If that doesn't work you may also have some kind of absolute positioning involved. If this is the case, and is applied to the `i` elements, then you'll need to remove it.

But without seeing the style applied to the `i` elements it's a bit impossible to tell.

#### update

Ah, ok so the negative top margin was causing the issue. In order to get your text and your icons to align on the same line you'll have to wrap the text with a span and apply a `float:left` to it.

```
<span style="display: block; float:left;">2:54 - 6:54</span>
<i class="icos-refresh" style="float: right; margin-right: 2px"></i>
<i class="icos-acces-denied-sign" style="float: right; margin-right: 2px"></i>
```

However I'd recommend that you not use inline styles and extract these to specific css classes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I'm back in the office, I completely forgot the `<i>` element's styling. As soon as I'm back in the office, I will lookup all the styles applied to those and will post it. Thanks.

Comment: after checking the styles applied to the `i` icons the width and heights are defined to be 16px (same as the icon) I've updated the question with more findings. Thanks again.

Comment: @hjavaher Heh, just updated my answer as you did with your question by the look of things :)